# iScroll modal bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, iscroll

I am loading external page via bootstrap modal manager by loading iframe inside modal when it is clicked and i have tried to add iscroll inside modal window but no luck.

Code for loading php page that has iframe inside of it

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict();
j(document).ready(function(){
j('#openBtn').on('click', function(){
// create the backdrop and wait for next modal to be triggered
j('body').modalmanager('loading');

setTimeout(function(){
j('.modal-body').load('loadtz.php', '', function(){
j('#full-width').modal({show:true});
});
}, 1000);
});
```

Code structure for loading div

```
<div id="full-width" class="modal container hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-header"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"     aria-hidden="true">x</button></div> 
<div class="modal-body">
</div>
</div>
```

I don't know if iscroll can be use without li elements inside - any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Hello this apparently is a bug with bootstrap animation. Then you must load your scroll div after the amimation of bootsrap modal end. See this sample http://t.co/T4sWxsKCsi